# Reduce not working

Tags: inequalities

I am trying to check some inequality with Reduce function, but Mathematica doesn't work.
The code I am using is:

```
Reduce[k + (3 E^((a + b) k) k (E^(-a k)/3 - (4 E^(-b k))/
          3))/(3 E^((a + b) k) + E^(b k) (1 + a k) - 
       4 E^(a k) (1 + b k)) + (9 E^(2 (a + b) k) k (6 E^((a + b) k) + 
         E^(b k) (2 + a k (2 + a k)) - 
         4 E^(a k) (2 + b k (2 + b k))) (E^(-a k)/3 - (4 E^(-b k))/
           3)^2)/(2 (3 E^((a + b) k) + E^(b k) (1 + a k) - 
          4 E^(a k) (1 + b k))^3) > k && k > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0, {k, 
  a, b}, Reals]
```

I see that my expression is quite terrible in order to expect some suitable condition for the variables, but I don't know what's going on. Mathematica just says 'This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce'.

Comment: Look at the result of `RegionPlot3D[
 k + (3 E^((a + b) k) k (E^(-a k)/3 - (4 E^(-b k))/
          3))/(3 E^((a + b) k) + E^(b k) (1 + a k) - 
       4 E^(a k) (1 + b k)) + (9 E^(2 (a + b) k) k (6 E^((a + b) k) + 
         E^(b k) (2 + a k (2 + a k)) - 
         4 E^(a k) (2 + b k (2 + b k))) (E^(-a k)/3 - (4 E^(-b k))/
           3)^2)/(2 (3 E^((a + b) k) + E^(b k) (1 + a k) - 
          4 E^(a k) (1 + b k))^3) > k && k > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0, {a, 
  0, 5}, {b, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 20]`.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks, but I'm searching for some inequality condition less harder than the original and the plot doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
f=Simplify[k+(3 E^((a+b)k)k(E^(-a k)/3-(4 E^(-b k))/3))/(3 E^((a+b)k)+E^(b k)(1+a k)-
  4 E^(a k)(1+b k))+(9 E^(2(a+b)k)k(6 E^((a+b)k)+E^(b k)(2+a k(2+a k))-4 E^(a k)
  (2+b k(2+b k)))(E^(-a k)/3-(4 E^(-b k))/3)^2)/(2(3 E^((a+b)k)+E^(b k)(1+a k)-
  4 E^(a k)(1+b k))^3)> k,k>0&&a>0&&b>0]
```

shows me

```
((-4*E^(a*k) + E^(b*k))*k*(...stuff...)/(...more stuff...) > 0
```

My first thought is to make `(-4*E^(a*k) + E^(b*k)` negative and

```
f/.{a->1,b->1,k->1}
```

should accomplish that. It instantly returns

```
False
```

So your original inequality is false under the conditions that the three parameters are greater than zero

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still have some doubts about it and it would be amazing if you have some time to answer them. In your first equation I suppose that instead of $>k$ in the rhs it should be $>0$, I think it's a typo. On the other hand, I don't see clearly how making $(-4*e^{a*k}+ e^{b*k}$ negative and evaluating the function in those values (which results in a false statement) implies that the inequality is false for all the three parameters greater than zero. I don't know if it's a silly question but i've been thinking about it and I still don't get it your reasoning. Thanks!.

Comment: YES! ">k" should have been ">0" Fixed! I was cleaning up the format and made that mistake. Excellent catch. I usually tell people to carefully check my work, but I left that out this time and you did it anyway. THANK YOU! Next for your expr>k && k>0&&a>0&&b>0 What I showed was that it was not true in general. Ideally Reduce should return a set of conditions for k,a,b that would make it true, but your expr is complicated enough that Reduce couldn't crack that and nothing else I've tried is able to give precise conditions. `{k,a,b}=RandomReal[{0,10},3]` make it true about 60% of the time. Sorry

Comment: `Reduce` can't even do this MUCH simpler problem `Reduce[-4 E^(a k)+E^(b k)>0&&k>0&&a>0&&b>0,{a,b,k},Reals]` so your full problem appears far out of reach unless someone can come up with a very bright idea.

Comment: You might consider generating 10^n  points (a,b,k), perhaps randomly, discard any which make your inequality false, display all the rest of the points and see whether there are any holes or gaps or half spaces that lack points and then generate more points to verify that observation. I have done that in a very limited way and haven't seen anything other than a uniform cloud of points. But maybe I just didn't do enough or didn't look in the right places. If you could find that then maybe you could develop that into a conjecture to test. But I've run out of ideas. Good luck on this.

Comment: Thank you for your time :). Yeah, I wanted a set of conditions for k,a,b but seems that this problem is terrible for any software and in general it can't be done for arbitrary k,a and b. I don't really know what to do now. Thanks again for your time, it seems that without giving values and checking those values it is impossible to solve this problem.